# How do you hide or remove a UISearchBar from a UITableView

Tags: uisearchbar

I have a UISearchBar that was defined in the storyboard and on certain uses of this view, I would like to remove the search bar from the view.

I have tried:

```
[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar setHidden:YES];
```

and even

```
[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar removeFromSuperview];
```

But this leaves an empty space where the search bar was instead of closing it up to the top of the view.

I was thinking I should be able to just set it to nil but it's a readonly property and you can't do that.

There is probably a very simply way to do this that I just can't seem to find or figure out. Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For my needs, this actually did turn out to be quite simple. Using this:

```
[self.tableView setTableHeaderView:nil];
```

Since I don't have anything else in the table header view and do not need to add it back at some later time (I only need it when a new instance is created).

Hopefully this will help someone else struggling to find this in the future.